# Where do library C header files go on Linux

Tags: c++, c, header, apt-get

Embarrassingly basic question.  `sudo apt-get install libmemcached6` - where do the .h's and .o's or .so's live in a typical install on a Linux machine (Ubuntu)?  And, how do I make sure g++ can pick them up?

Comment: g++ can pick them up if they are properly installed because they should be in the PATH. Otherwise, you could compile the library yourself statically and place the output somewhere in a folder of your choice.

Comment: The question is _which_ folder to put them in

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They go to /usr/include and /usr/lib. If you use the -l option (for the libraries) it should find them from these standard places. If you include using `<file.h>` it should also get it from the right place.

Comment: Found the so in /usr/lib.  No header in /usr/include.  Is this likely something not included in an apt-get install and I'll just need to acquire the source myself?

Comment: mostprobably your library has a -dev version that installs the header and this one just installs the runtime requirements (aka the .so)

try doing 

apt-cache search libmemcached6 

and see if there's a libmemcached6-dev package for development files. that will add the header file

Comment: Thanks, I needed the -dev version.  g++ myfile.cpp works clean now.

Comment: Linking with -lmemcached seems like it compiles but fails to link the C functions in, not sure how to tell where to find them (or where they are.)

Comment: @djechlin, try running `objdump -T /usr/lib/libmemcached.so.6` and checking to make sure the names match what you have in your code.

Comment: You wouldn't typically compile like that, no. You'd compile each `.cpp` file into a `.o` file and link them in a separate step. See the gcc manual I linked in my answer for some clarity on how that works, but you might try moving the `-l` argument after your `.cpp` files. Order matters.

Comment: Yes, the -l needs to go after the .cpp.  I know exactly why this is, just had no chance of actually remembering that technical point.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: If I have a `.a` file to which I wish to statically link. Should I place that as well in `/usr/lib`?

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu (and other Debian variants) you can use the `dpkg` command to find out. For example:

```
$ dpkg -L libxml2
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libxml2
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/README
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2/README.Debian
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
```

As you can see, Debian packages don't typically include the `.h` files; those are normally in corresponding `-dev` packages. So you can find the header files here:

```
$ dpkg -L libxml2-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/TODO.gz
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/README
/usr/share/doc/libxml2-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/aclocal
/usr/share/aclocal/libxml2.m4
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man3
/usr/share/man/man3/libxml.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/xml2-config.1.gz
/usr/include
/usr/include/libxml2
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/HTMLtree.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlreader.h
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlschemastypes.h
...
```

As for `gcc`, [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) explains how it searches for header files. Note that this is different and separate from [using `-l` to instruct the linker to link with a certain library](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and the majority of the Unix-based systems, the libraries may be found on either of these two locations:

1. /usr/lib/
2. /usr/local/lib/

The difference between these two locations is that the latter is used for the third party libraries. So if you have published your own library or have installed one from a third party repository (for instance ppa),those files should go to `/usr/local/lib`.

The storage of header files can be understood using the above analogy. The folders are:

1. /usr/include/
2. /usr/local/include/