# How to install .d files of a D library using automake?

Tags: installation, libraries, d, automake

What is the correct way to install (system-wide) a D library (on a GNU system, at least) using `Makefile.am`?

Here is my code to install the static and shared libraries:

```
install-data-local:
        install librdf_dlang.a librdf_dlang.so $(libdir)
```

The remaining question is how to install `.d` files for developers to use my library?

Particularly, what should be the installation directory for `.d` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a system-wide installation of D libraries and source (interface files I presume), then the most common places are `/usr/include/<project name>` or `/usr/local/include/<project name>` as long as it does not clash with some existing C/C++ project that stores header files there. Some D programmers prefer `/usr/include/d/` or `/usr/local/include/d/` as well...

I for an example use `/usr/di` (D imports) for this purpose and my library projects have all their interface files there. I will explain why I do not like to have separate project directories there.

No matter what directory you pick, you need to update your compiler search paths.

Here is a part of my dmd.conf:

```
[Environment64]
DFLAGS=-I/usr/include/dmd/phobos -I/usr/include/dmd/druntime/import -I/usr/di -L-L/usr/lib64 -L--export-dynamic -fPIC
```

, and ldc2.conf looks like:

```
    // default switches appended after all explicit command-line switches
    post-switches = [
        "-I/usr/include/d/ldc",
        "-I/usr/include/d",
        "-I/usr/di",
        "-L-L/usr/lib64",
    ];
```

If you prefer to have a separate directory for every project, you would end up with `-I<path>` for each of them. - I really do not like this approach. However, it is very popular among developers so it is really up to you how to organise the D import files. I know how much developers dislike the Java approach with `domain.product.packages`, but this nicely fits into a single place where all D interface files are and most importantly there are no clashes because of the *domain/product* part...

Answer (score 1):

According to [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) (and e.g. this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10729484/272735))

```
/usr/local/include
```

looks a strong candidate on a "linux/unix-like system". See especially [note 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#cite_note-9):

> Historically and strictly according to the standard, /usr/local is for data that must be stored on the local host (as opposed to /usr, which may be mounted across a network). Most of the time /usr/local is used for installing software/data that are not part of the standard operating system distribution (in such case, /usr would only contain software/data that are part of the standard operating system distribution). It is possible that the FHS standard may in the future be changed to reflect this de facto convention.

I have no idea about Windows.

Comment: isn't `/include` only for C header files?

Comment: I looked into some Ubuntu D packages. They use `include/d`

Comment: @porton `/include` is for [include files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) and is language neutral. C header files is just one (albeit the most common) example.